# PHP Dynamic URL in Multilengual Web

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Hi everybody and tks in advance for your help!
I have a multilengual site made in a similar way to [this example](http://www.queryadmin.com/1036/building-multilingual-php-website/). Everything is working just fine, but now I want to make that the URL change according to the languague selected. For example, if my page is called **perfil.php** when I select english languague, should be **profile.php**, and all the links in the web should translate to english too. I was surfing another questions but the majority offers a solution through htaccess. This should work, but I need to store that configuration (or translations) into my database so the user can change it when they want to.

Any ideas?
Thank you again!

Comment: you should save that names and use when lang is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constants in some files called language files and then require/include them by language selected:

english.php

```
const PROFILE = "profile";
```

spanish.php

```
const PROFILE = "perfil";
```

main file:

```
require $language_selected . ".php";
echo '<a href="' . PROFILE . '.php">';
```

Comment: Thanks Amir. That solution will work for the links. But something I missed to explain in my question is this: the only page that really exists is "profile.php", so, when I put in the URL or link "perfil.php" has to show me the profile.php content (without using htaccess). Is there a way that you know to acomplish that?

Comment: if you cannot modify htaccess, you should create perfil.php and require/include profile.php contents!

Comment: you can use routers to do this too! 
like: altorouter.com

Comment: Altorouter is the answer I think!!! I didn't know it, but looks pretty good!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This part should be a comment (but its a bit long)

The method described in the link you provided is a reasonable way to implement the choice of language, but a poor way to detect the choice.

Your browser already tells servers what language(s) it thinks they [should respond in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language). And most webservers have a mechanism for [multiplexing different language content](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html). However the latter means hard-wiring the choice of the browser without providing an easy means for overriding the behaviour.

The approach I have used before is something like this:

```
 $use_lang='en-GB';
 if (isset($_COOKIE['userlang']) 
    && is_language_supported($_COOKIE['userlang'])) {
    $use_lang=$_COOKIE['userlang'];
 } else if ($proposedlang=supported_lang_in($_SERVER['Accept-Language'])) {
    $use_lang=$proposedlang;
 }

 function supported_lang_in($str)
 {
     $l=array();
     $opts=explode(',', $str);
     foreach ($opts as $v) {
       list($p, $weight)=explode(';', $v);
       if ($weight) {
          list($dummy, $weight)=explode('=', $weight);
          $weight=float($weight);
       } 
       if (!$weight) {
          $weight=1.0;
       }
       if (isset($l[$weight])) {
          $weight-=0.001;
       }
       $l[$weight]=$p;
     }
     krsort($p); // preferred first
     foreach ($p as $proposed) {
        if ('*'==$proposed) {
            return false;
        }
        if (is_language_supported($proposed)) {
            return $lang;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

Now on to the problem you asked about....

Maintaining different URLs to reference the same content then dereference the language within the content seems a very byzantine solution to the problem. Not only do you have to map the input to the URL but you need to rewrite any URLs in the output to the appropriate representation.

While having semantically meaningful URLs is a definite bonus, going to great length to tailor these dynamically is not perhaps not the best use of your time.

Comment: "While having semantically meaningful URLs is a definite bonus, going to great length to tailor these dynamically is not perhaps not the best use of your time." >> I agree with that but... what is the alternative for solving my problem? Tks!

Comment: I would leave the URLs in the default language - when was the last time you navigated round a site by typing in URLs? They aren't even visible on most mobile clients.